# Windows Server 2008 - Zone Scavenging - "This zone can be scavenged after"

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, a-record, dynamic-dns

I have set up DNS scavenging on our Windows Server 08 R2 boxes as we had records in there that were duplicated and some dating back to 2004!

I set the no-refresh and refresh-after intervals both to 3 days, zone scavenging is enabled on each zone and at a server level the Ageing settings are enabled for scavenging too.

However, when we run the scavenge nothing happens (even after a few days) so we checked the settings again and found a box that said "this zone can be scavenged after" and the date was 11/01/2014...

Is there a way to change this value so it is for example, today - waiting until 2014 for a simple DNS scavenge is a bit much...

Cheers,
Myles

P.S: I followed the "holy grail" guide to Windows DNS Scavenging for all the processes: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/03/19/don-t-be-afraid-of-dns-scavenging-just-be-patient.aspx

Comment: Myles, did you reload the zone after setting scavenging up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting up scavenging on a DNS zone in Windows, you need to reload the zone in order for the proper "this zone can be scavenged after" date to be calculated and set.

Reloading the zone should fix your issue.

Comment: After the next reload, the timestamp should update itself to the current time + the current refresh interval